# List files in website directory without index.html

Tags: javascript

If a directory on a webserver doesn't have any html files (e.g. index.html), then when you navigate to that url, typically you just see a list of the files in that directory (unless .htaccess was changed to prevent this). Is it possible to get a list of these files in javascript?

Comment: Javascript is executed on the client pc, and there it can't see the website directory files.

Comment: I am not a frontend dev. How is it that the browser shows me a list of files in a directory if there is no .htaccess?

Comment: I want to set up a gallery of images on a web page. I want to know if I can use javascript to get these filenames as long as I put them into a directory with an html file

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a get_files function

```
    var files;

    function getFilesInFolder(folderServerRelativeUrl) {        
     var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var web = context.get_web();
    var folder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderServerRelativeUrl);
    files = folder.get_files();
    context.load(files);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnFailure));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you write code to display something on the web, you are using a server-side language. HTML is a server-side language, but has extremely limited programming capabilities - can't read the server file system, cannot loop, etc.

So, to do what you are asking you need a server-side language. Either PHP or node.js or Python etc. Almost all webhosts already include PHP, but you can now find some (a2, webhostpython) with the other two. There are TONS of tutorials online for doing what you want with PHP. Tons.

So, to be clear, if you want to code your server-side in javascript, you need to have node.js installed on that server. To use PHP, it's almost certainly already there.

PHP files are identical to HTML files, except they end in `.php` instead of `.html`, which allows them to process PHP code between the `<?php` and `?>` tags. Generally, PHP files are either pure PHP-only, *OR* they are a mix of HTML and PHP, with the PHP code included on the page between these tags.

Here is a basic tutorial to give you an idea how it would work:

https://daveismyname.blog/creating-an-image-gallery-from-a-folder-of-images-automatically

Answer (score -2):

What you can do is create an endpoint that would point out all the files that you need to display and make an API call to the endpoint using JS